# mysql dump file exported in workbench is a blank sql file

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When a schema was exported from workbench, a mysql dump File was created. But the file was empty. When it executed, there was no error. Why would that happen?

Answer (score 2):

had the same issue first, i found its needed to select the following selections:

[image]